# Java Libgdx get screenshot very slow

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx, screenshot

I write a game for android using libgdx. If the user opens the pause menu I take a screenshot of the current game, blur it and use it as background for the options menu. This works fine but the code for getting the screenshot is very slow. It takes about 0.8 seconds on average using the code below...

Is there another way to take a screenshot in libgdx which is much faster?
If not, when the user opens the options menu I could try to just keep rendering the game, pause the game logic and blur the screen and draw the options on top.. If this is the only fast way, how could one **blur** the screen? I found [this link](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson5) but I didn't get it to work.
If it is possible I prefer the solution with the screenshot because it is much easier...

Code to get the screenshot (from [official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot)):

```
public static Pixmap getScreenshot(){
    long start = TimeUtils.millis();

    byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);

    long time = TimeUtils.millis()-start;
    Gdx.app.log("INFO", "Time for screenshot in sec.: " + time);  // about 0.8 seconds

    return pixmap;
}
```

I use the resulting Pixmap to draw my texture.

**EDIT:**

My code now with the answer of Deniz Yılmaz for getting the screenshot fast:

```
public Texture getScreenshot(){

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGB888);

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.bind();
    Gdx.gl.glCopyTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_RGB, 0, 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), 0);
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Draw your scene to a FrameBuffer and use that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 could you be a bit more specific? I'd love to see a clear and thorough answer that describes a better way for making a screenshot then the documentation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you, may you provide a short example how to draw (a texture?) to a Framebuffer and (use a Shader??) to blur it?

Comment: where do you calling getScreenshot() ?

Comment: @DenizYılmaz When the user presses the back key (android), I call `getScreenshot()` and pass the resulting texture to a new Screen class as background to display the options menu....

Comment: Can you try with a pressed another key? i have same code with you but mine is in if condition 
if(state==0){state++; getscreenshot() ;  }

Comment: Because pause may be cause flush in the GPU.

Comment: @DenizYılmaz I tried without button press to just call it in the render method but I just get a white screen... For you it works?

Comment: I was testing on desktop so it was working but in android i got white screen as you but i also solve this problem. I used RGB color instead of RGBA in both gl and texture creation. Format.RGB888 GL20.GL_RGB And it works for me on android too. But some phone gpus require power of 2 size textures. My zenfone 2 worked without it.

Comment: @DenizYılmaz Thank you, it works now!! :) You are a OpenGL master!! ..do you know how blur the resulting Texture?

Comment: I guess you must use shader for this but i will research for another way tomorrow.

Comment: @DenizYılmaz Thank you! :) That would be great!

Comment: @DenizYılmaz Hi, I wanted to ask if you know another way for blurring the resulting screenshot texture instead of applying a shader? Thank you..

Comment: still searching about it but i guess shaders are easiest way to do it.i was tryin blur with a mipmaps but mipmaps are pain in libgdx :(

Comment: @DenizYılmaz Thank you for searching! Ok, do you know how to do it with shaders?

Comment: First look [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/08/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-12-Using-GLSL-Shaders-and-creating-a-Mesh.aspx) for shader tutorial 

and look [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson5) for blur shaders and logic

Comment: @DenizYılmaz I didn't get the shaders to work, but thank you very much for your help! At least my original problem was solved! PS: I have working code to blur a Pixmap but can't get it to work with our Texture...

Comment: I tried this and is working perfectly on Android, but I'm getting a black texture on iOS, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually taking screenshot is not slow. 
Slow part is data transfer between GPU and CPU  so any other way to get pixels wont be faster so much.

But also there are openGl codes helping us right here. 
You can use opengl codes via Gdx.gl class.

```
void glCopyTexImage2D(  
    GLenum      target,         //Target Opengl Texture
    GLint       level,          //Mipmap level
    GLenum      internalformat, //Color format
    GLint       x,
    GLint       y,
    GLsizei     width,
    GLsizei     height,
    GLint       border);
```

This function copy pixels into a 2D texture image but not bringing them to CPU.
You just belong a FBO at GPU. 
In libgdx first you must bind texture to openGl's texture with a method. 
This texture can be empty screen sized texture or you can use old texture you wont use again.

```
Texture.bind();
```

or

```
Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(Opengltexture, texture.getTextureObjectHandle());
```

For bounding and taking screen

1. Enable GPUtexture type.
2. Activate for exact GPUtexture
3. Call texture bind method
4. Call opengl function for active GPUtexture
5. Disable GPUtexture type.

Here is what code look like :

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
texture.bind();
Gdx.gl.glCopyTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_RGBA,0, 0,width , height, 0);
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Be aware binding is only active in 1 and 5. My fault was here because i tried to bind texture in create method and had got black screen.

**BE AWARE!!!**

- On android, it needs opengl es 2.0 . You can edit manifest to make sure unsupported devices cant download your game.

  > < uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  >   android:required="true"  >
- RGBA format color space doesnt    supported. So make sure you are
  using Format.RGB for both opengl    function and texture creation.
- Result texture will be flipped vertically because of openGl matrix
  system.  So you have to fix it manually.

I also suggest you to look at fragments and shaders.
It seems like hard but actually enjoyable.

Comment: Thank you!! That means that `Texture.bind()` takes a screenshot which is hold in GPU? Do you have a short example how to apply a blur filter to this texture? I created an empty Texture in screen size and called `.bind()` and draw it but the result was just a white screen instead of a screenshot...?

Comment: No you missunderstood me . 
I will try to explain but im not an expert at opengl. 
First i assume that you know about GPU . Its graphic processor hold all data about your sprites. 
When you draw texture CPU sending texture data to GPU and GPU drawing it.
When you bind a texture to opengl texture. Opengl storing your texture data with a adress value. 
You can call this adress in libgdx via GL20 like GL20.GL_TEXTURE0. 
When you have a binded texture in GPU ,now you can use openGl functions.

Comment: Maybe you can look at this link 
https://open.gl/textures
It can be usefull for opengl part.
You can use opengl functions via Gdx.gl class.
Gdx.gl.anyopenglfunction like.

Comment: My code is: `Gdx.gl.glCopyTexImage2D(Gdx.gl20.GL_TEXTURE0, 0, Gdx.gl.GL_RGB, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), 0);` but it still shows just a white screen... Is this correct? May I have to put it in the render method?

Comment: I edited answer for exact code :). 
İ was trying to figure it out and i just did :D

Comment: Great, thanks! :) Sorry, are you sure that you updated the answer, I can't see the change..?

Comment: I couldnt edit code part . kind of bug i guess . now edited i am sure and  also tested.

Comment: Thank you!! I edited my post with your answer, can you check if this is correct, I still get just a white screen when I draw the resulting texture...?